# Install a package using composer. How? Where?

Tags: php, json, composer-php, package

I'm fairly new to PHP and Composer and used Linux 20 years ago. I'm developing a website on a shared hosted server (Hostinger) and trying to install a package from Cardinity (they take VISA payments). I want to use this package from my website which I've hand written in HTML/PHP/MySQL etc.

The instruction from cardinity is to execute the following (from https://github.com/cardinity/cardinity-sdk-php):

```
$ php composer.phar require cardinity/cardinity-sdk-php
```

I've changed this to:

```
$ php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar require cardinity/cardinity-sdk-php
```

So that it runs without error.

I have two questions which are:

1. Am I right in thinking that composer will locate and download the package (and sub-packages it requires) for me? I don't have to do anything other than execute this line?
2. In which directory do I execute this?

My website is in **/home/u123456789/public_html**. I've executed the above statement in **/home/u123456789/public_html** and ended up with **composer.json** and **composer.lock** files in that directory, as well as a **vendor** folder. However, my website doesn't pick up the package. When I execute a simple **test.php** file with the following code in (as advised by Cardinity):

```
use Cardinity\Client;
$client = Client::create([
    'consumerKey' => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
    'consumerSecret' => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
]);
```

I get the error: Fatal error: *Class 'Cardinity\Client' not found in /home/u123456789/public_html/dev/test.php on line 32* which is on the Client::create line. My **test.php** file is in the directory `/home/u123456789/public_html/dev`.

Does **test.php** have to be in the same directory as **composer.json**, **composer.lock** and **vendor**?

Comment: Composer generates an autoload file in `vendor/autoload.php` which you manually need to include in your app. So add `require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';` in the top of the first loaded PHP file. and you should be set.

Comment: You can read more in composers manual: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: @Magnus - thank you very much. I've been bashing my head against a wall for the last two days. Additionally: Happy New Year to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try and make it a bit harder for hackers and place items not as per documentation and in properties that follow your own naming convention.

Also add a security measure if some one does try to access the "default". Someone having your keys as do some real harm with a refund.